# Anova with missing F and P values

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, anova, generalized-linear-model

[Following](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/274151/anova-to-compare-models), I am not sure of how to interpret this anova output. Model 1,2,3 are all nested in model 4, model 1 is also nested in model 2 but not model 3 because indus is not in model 3 and similarly indus is in model 2 but not in model 3. Model 1 has 7 independent variables, both model 2 and 3 have 12 independent variables while model 4 has 13 independent variables. I am aware that anova makes statistical sense for nested lm [objects](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/anova.lm.html). Upon using AIC, I realized model 3 is better but how do I know that model 3 is better from this anova output especially that the F value and P value for model 3 is missing? data(Boston) from library("MASS") in R.
[image]